# How to use mysql function in querydsl with sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, querydsl

The phone number in the database is encrypted, so I have to use the decryption function. So I wrote the code like this, but it didn't work. How can I make it?

Here is my code

```
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
            if(StringUtils.hasText(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd()) && StringUtils.hasText(memberVO.getSearchText())) {
                if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("memNm")) {
                    builder.and(info.memNm.contains(memberVO.getSearchText()));
                }
                if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("nickNm")) {
                    builder.and(info.nickNm.contains(memberVO.getSearchText()));            
                }
                if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("hpNo")) {             
                    //FN_DECRYPT is not working
                    builder.and(info.nickNm.prepend("FN_DECRYPT(").append(")").contains(memberVO.getSearchText()));
                }
            }
```

And I want type like this in sql.

```
WHERE FN_DECRYPT(hpNo) LIKE '%010-0000-0000%'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it

```
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    if(StringUtils.hasText(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd()) && StringUtils.hasText(memberVO.getSearchText())) {
        if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("memNm")) {
            builder.and(info.memNm.contains(memberVO.getSearchText()));
        }
        if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("nickNm")) {
            builder.and(info.nickNm.contains(memberVO.getSearchText()));            
        }
        if(memberVO.getSearchTypeCd().equals("hpNo")) {                             
            builder.and(Expressions.booleanTemplate("FN_DECRYPT({0}) LIKE '%" + memberVO.getSearchText().replaceAll("-", "") + "%'", info.hpNo));
        }
    }
```